# Can hyperbolic functions be defined in terms of trigonometric functions?

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

For example, can $\sinh x$ be written as a function of $\sin x$?

Another question, are hyperbolic functions dependent of their trigonometric correspondence in any way?

Answer (score 70):

Yes. For example 
\begin{align*}
\sinh x &= -i \sin(ix) \\
\cosh x &= \cos(ix) \\
\tanh x &= -i \tan(ix) \\
\end{align*}

These identities come from the definitions,

$$ \sin x = \frac{e^{xi}-e^{-xi}}{2i} \text{ and } \sinh x = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2} $$
and similar for cosine and tangent.

Comment: From this definition, can we say that a hyperbolic function is a trigonometric function with complex variable and with a complex coefficient for an odd function?

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning the link to [Osborne's rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/138842/72968) here.

Comment: @Typhon not sure what you mean, $$ -i\sin(ix) = \frac 1 i \frac{e^{xi^2}-e^{-xi^2}}{2i} = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2} = \sinh x $$

Comment: @LeoAuthersh I get what you're saying, but I would not word it like that. Trig functions are already defined for complex variables, i.e. $\cosh z = \cos iz$ for $z\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: @Dando18 Are all the trigonometric functions with complex variable hyperbolic functions? Or are hyperbolic functions just one of many classifications of trigonometric function with complex variable?

Comment: @LeoAuthersh no. Simply think of their definitions $\cosh z \equiv 1/2(e^z + e^{-z}),\ \ z\in\mathbb C$ and $\cos z \equiv 1/2(e^{zi}+e^{-zi}),\ z\in\mathbb C$. Both are defined for complex input, but we just have this nice identity that $\cosh z = \cos(iz)$.

Comment: Good. So, it means that both circular functions and hyperbolic functions can be defined in real function as well as complex function. But coshz = Cos(iz) is just another spectacular equation. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 48):

Besides the connections between hyperbolic and circular functions which arise from substitutions involving imaginary arguments the functions can also be related using only real arguments via the [Gudermannian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function) defined as $$\text{gd}(x)=\int_0^x\text{sech}\,t\,dt$$
This leads to identities such as $\sinh x = \tan (\text{gd}\,x)$ and $\sin x = \tanh( \text{gd}^{-1}\, x)$.

Comment: Now this is something *quite unusual*.

Answer (score 12):

This may not be what you mean, but the phrase "as a function of" sometimes has a narrow and precise meaning. Specifically, "$x$ can be written as a function of $y$" means that there is a function $f$ such that $x = f(y)$.

To answer that narrow question, $\sinh x$ cannot be written as a function of $\sin x$ because $\sin$ is periodic along the real axis but $\sinh$ is not.

More specifically:

1. Assume $\forall{x \in R},~ \sinh(x) = f(\sin(x))$
2. Therefore, $\sinh(0) = f(\sin(0))$ and $\sinh(2\pi) = f(\sin(2\pi))$
3. Therefore, $\sinh(0) = f(0) = \sinh(2\pi)$

The last equation is not true.

Comment: Good point about about the need for clear terminology. In particular, the question “can $\sinh x$ be written as a function of $\sin x$?” (answer: _no_) is very different from “can $\sinh$ be written as a function of $\sin$?”, in fact that's somewhat trivially possible through e.g. $\sinh = \backslash x \to \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2 + 0\cdot \sin x$.