# Can someone give a proof for this hyperbolic rule

Tags: trigonometry

can someone please give a proof for this with a little explanation

$$\cosh(x)^2-\sinh(x)^2 = 1$$

Comment: Write out the definitions of the functions in terms of $\exp(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use
$$\cosh(x)=\cos(\mathrm{i}x)$$
$$\sinh(x)=-\mathrm{i}\sin(\mathrm{i}x)$$

to turn it into

$$\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$$

Also, I suggest you to read this question and its answers: [Can hyperbolic functions be defined in terms of trignometric functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388001/can-hyperbolic-functions-be-defined-in-terms-of-trignometric-functions)

Answer (score 0):

$$\cosh^2{x}-\sinh^2x=\left(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}\right)^2=$$
$$=\frac{e^{2x}+2+e^{-2x}-e^{2x}+2-e^{-2x}}{4}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

One more attempt:

$\cosh(x) =(1/2)(e^x +e^{-x});$

$\sinh(x) = (1/2)(e^x -e^{-x}).$

$\cosh^2(x) - \sinh^2(x)=$

$(\cosh(x)-\sinh(x))$
$×(\cosh(x) +\sinh(x))=$

$(e^{-x})(e^x)=1$.